# streaming images from wcf to asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have wcf service(C#) which get (Bitmap)image from the special device and asp.net page.
I want to streaming this images to my Web page. I try send this images  from callback func and display them in ImageBox in web page, but it is to slow, because my device is 25 fps.
How solve this problem?Need help and you device

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following thread, Maybe the tips there can help you:

[Efficient way to send images via WCF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829269/efficient-way-to-send-images-via-wcf)